# Writing down TokenID for the discord bot prompts a Runtime error

Tags: python, discord.py, runtime-error, bots

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import music

cogs = [music]
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='-', intents = discord.Intents.all())

for i in range(len(cogs)):
    cogs[i].setup(client)
client.run('TOKEN')

 ________Music.py________

import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import youtube_dl

class music(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client
    @commands.command()
    async def join(self,ctx):
        if ctx.author.voice is None:
            await ctx.send("You are not in a voice channel!")
        voice_channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
        if ctx.voice_client is None:
            await voice_channel.connect()
        else:
            await ctx.voice_client.move_to(voice_channel)
    @commands.command()
    async def disconnect(self,ctx):
        await ctx.voice_client.disconnect()
    @commands.command()
    async def play(self,ctx,url):
        ctx.voice_client.stop()
        FFMPEG_OPTIONS = {'before_options': '-reconnect 1 -reconnect_streamed 1 -reconnect_delay_max 5', 'options':'-vn'}
        YDL_OPTIONS = {'format':"bestaudio"}
        vc = ctx.voice_client
        
        with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(YDL_OPTIONS) as ydl:
            info = ydl.extract_info(url, download=False)
            url2 = info['formats'][0]['url']
            source = await discord.FFmpegOpusAudio.from_probe(url2,**FFMPEG_OPTIONS)
            vc.play(source)
    @commands.command()
    async def pause(self,ctx):
        await ctx.voice_client.pause()
        await ctx.send("Paused⏸")
    @commands.command()
    async def resume(self,ctx):
        await ctx.voice_client.resume()
        await ctx.send("Resume⏯")
        
def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(music(client))
```

I am constantly getting a Runtime error as `RuntimeError: Cannot close a running event loop` and I don't know why when I delete the line containing the TokenID it shows no error and just as I rewrite the client.run() command it comes up again.

I followed a Youtube tutorial for this. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jHZlvRr9KxM

Answer (score 0):

Try that as Main:

```
import sys
import traceback

from discord.ext import commands


class Main(commands.Bot):
    initial_extensions = ['cogs.music']

client = MusicBot(command_prefix=commands.when_mentioned_or('-'))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for extension in client.initial_extensions:
        try:
            client.load_extension(extension)
        except Exception as e:
            print(f'Failed to load extension {extension}.', file=sys.stderr)
            traceback.print_exc()

client.run('TOKEN')
```

And before you do that, check that the token you are using is correct

Comment: ```NameError: name 'MusicBot' is not defined``` what is this MusicBot?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry!
Here is the new code:

```
import sys
import traceback

from discord.ext import commands


class Main(commands.Bot):
    initial_extensions = ['cogs.music']

client = Main(command_prefix=commands.when_mentioned_or('-'))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for extension in client.initial_extensions:
        try:
            client.load_extension(extension)
        except Exception as e:
            print(f'Failed to load extension {extension}.', file=sys.stderr)
            traceback.print_exc()

client.run('TOKEN')
```

Comment: Failed to load extension cogs.music.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-14-c6cec910a3ca>", line 16, in <module>
    client.load_extension(extension)
  File "C:\Users\Prabuddh Mathur\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 674, in load_extension
    spec = importlib.util.find_spec(name)
  File "C:\Users\Prabuddh Mathur\anaconda3\lib\importlib\util.py", line 94, in find_spec
    parent = __import__(parent_name, fromlist=['__path__'])
```ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cogs' ```
And then again good old run time error 

Comment: You have to create a new folder called "cogs" in your project folder. And then pull the musik.py into it. And did you check the token? If you don't know how to do this, go to the Discord Developer page and go to your bot, then to the bot tab on the right and click on Copy. Now you insert the token into the client.run () with quotation marks.

Comment: Hey! I did try changing the token and even regenerated it 3 times now, but don't know why it is just not working. If you don't mind could you please join me on Discord and guide me through... my account is ```Prabuddh#0947``` .. wish to see you there.